# Zend Framework - Search Lucene for exact phrase

Tags: zend-framework, full-text-search

is there any way to Query the Index of `Zend_Search_Lucene` for an exact match ?

```
$keyword = 'Summer 2009';
```

when i use :

```
$myIndex->find($keyword)
```

i am also receiving "Summer , 2009, Summer 2009" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying for a double-quoted string ought to do it:

```
$keyword = '"Summer 2009"';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet will result in a term query where Zend Search will generate a set of tokens which will be tried against all the index fields. This is because if you pass a string to find() it is passed into the Query_Parser().

You will need to specifically create a Phrase Query for this situation.

It would look something like:

```
   $query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Phrase(array('Summer', '2009'));
   $index->find($query);
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.query-api.html contains more information.